# how can i use the i variable outside the for loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I want to use the value of 'i' in a certain point, like in the example below.
  What i have tried to do didnt work, what else can i do?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);


       int i =1;
       int r;


       for(i=1;i<=100;i++){

          num = reader.nextInt();

          if (num == 55){
             r=i;
          }
          System.out.println(" 55 was typed in when i was equals to: "+r);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What did it *do*? Did you get a specific error message? Was `i` always equal to zero?

Comment: "the local variable r may not have been intialized"

Comment: You can fix that error by changing the second line to `int r=0;`.  It has to be _something_ in the event that 55 was never encountered.

Comment: Thank you! the code is okay now (:

Comment: What do you expect it to print when `num` is not 55? Did you mean to put your print statement inside the `if`?

Comment: No, that was just an example to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to initialize `r` where you declare it. Currently at Uni and learning myself though but I think that is it.

EDIT: Someone appears to have mentioned it in the comment too.